# Anchor in the entire element's rectangle

Tags: html, css

I have a list created by the following markup

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Bucuresti</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sighisoara</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tuzla</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Comorova-Neptun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Maramures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sinaia</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that the anchor has effect only on the bounding-rectangle created by the `a` tag, like below:[image][image]

I want to have, instead the anchor over the entire `li` tag. In the past, I have been putting the `li` inside the anchor tag ( `<a href="#"><li>Bucuresti</li></a>` ), but someone told me that it is wrong. What else can I do to get the effect I want without forcing the HTML syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links (`<a>`) are [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) by default, so they take up the width of their contents. By setting them to [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) instead `ul.menu a {display:block;}`, they'll take up the full width of their containing element by default and you can give them the ability to expand their height.

Answer (score 1):

You have some CSS to force your `<li>` elements to be the size and shape you want.  It's very likely that you can accomplish the same thing by applying that style to the `<a>` elements instead of the `<li>` elements.

[jsfiddle.net/92KKa](http://jsfiddle.net/92KKa/)

Comment: somebody posted a comment with `ul.menu li a { display: block; }` and that works. I asked for a bit of explanation.

Comment: @Victor - `display: block` may work beautifully, it all depends on your CSS for the `<li>`.  I updated the jsfiddle from my answer with a version that also compares just adding `display: block` to the links: [jsfiddle.net/92KKa/1](http://jsfiddle.net/92KKa/1/).  You can see that it sort of works, but it doesn't fill the `<li>`, in my case.  It wouldn't be an exact solution for every instance.

Answer (score 0):

add this style to anchor tag.

```
a{
  display:block;
}
```

anchor tag is an inline element and so it should be made block to occupy entire space.